# SQL query to display a matching in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

```
G  K  1  2  3  4 ...
K  2  2  1  1  3 ...              
1  2  2  4  2  2
2  1  4  2  5  2
```

I have two tables. Parent table and Student table. I need to find which parent or family has two kids in two different grades. The table above represents the number of parents that have kids in multiple different grades. For example grade K and grade 1 there are two families that have two kids that are both in K and first grade.

What I need to do is to come up with a query to find which families or parents have two kids in two different grades.

Comment: can you show what you've tried so far, what results that gives, and what results you are trying to get.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your desired outcome from the test data you provided?

Comment: This is a poor data structure for SQL.  Are you sure you don't have any other sources of information?

Comment: Is that your actual database table structure?  Can you better explain what the individual columns are?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in SQL, but it is an unpleasant query:

```
select (sum(k + `1` + `2` + . . . ) -
        (case when g = 'k' then k
              when g = `1` then `1`
              when g = `2` then `2`
              . . .
        )
       ) / 2
from table t;
```

The basic idea is that you take the sum of all the numbers on one line, subtract the ones along the diagonal, and divide by 2.  Note that this might not be right.  Families that have kids in three grades will be overcounted.  You do not have enough information to fix this.  More detailed information would help.